# Spritekit - Black screen for 5.5" displays (iPhone 6 Plus & iPhone 6s Plus)

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

In my SpriteKit project I added a sprite, which is the background of a 2d scrolling game. It's just one Sprite, that doesn't move and there are problems with it already.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

    var gameRunning = false

    var background: SKSpriteNode!


  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    gameRunning = false

    addBackground(0.0)

  }

  func addBackground(xPos: CGFloat) {
    background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    let ratio = screenSize.height / background.size.height
    background.setScale(ratio)

    background.position = CGPoint(x: xPos + background.size.width * 0.5, y: screenSize.height * 0.5)

    addChild(background)

  }
```

It works fine with all iPhones in the simulator except for iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s Plus. It just shows a black screen instead of my background.

Comment: please post all of your code. Where you create your scene, and where you are getting screenSize calculated.

Comment: did you include the @3x file

Comment: Yes, I included the @3x file.

Comment: Are you using AspectFill scene?

Comment: Whats the size of your texture, there are different maximums for different devices. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/AboutTextureAtlases/AboutTextureAtlases.html

Comment: I am using ResizeFill. The size of the texture is 5120 × 1280 pixels. Is it too big?